# iOS - Does Collection View keep every cell in memory?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, out-of-memory

I have a vertical collection view with 6 different types of cells... I observed that as I'm scrolling and new posts are being fetched from the server, (I'm using a paging mechanism (I'm fetching 20 by 20)) the app crashes with the log `Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue`

I also noticed that, that happens when there's more than 1 GB of RAM allocated, which is insane because there are about three posts presented at any given time... That happens when 400+ posts are fetched!

I suppose that the moment a cell is out of view, the collection view deallocates it. Is that right? So if a cell has an image, which I download/cache when it's about to be presented and then that cell is not visible anymore because I scrolled, then the image shouldn't be in memory. Right?

**Edit 1:**

What I'm doing in code, is to check at `willDisplay cell` if the cell that's about to be displayed, is the last one. If it is, then I am making a request to the server to bring me the next 20 posts, if any. When it does, I am appending the new posts to the posts array. After that I'm just reloading the collection view.

**Edit 2:**

I'm using the `PFImageView` from the `Parse SDK` as a caching mechanism

Comment: It doesn't deallocate cells, it reuses the ones that go out of screen and displays in place where a new one is supposed to appear. The collection view is not an issue here, but it's impossible to tell what is without seeing any code. You need to show how you store/cache your data.

Comment: Thank you for answering! Please check my edited question...

Answer (score 1):

No, they are reused.

The images **may** be in cache, and this is probably what is causing your huge memory usage. They should be removed from memory when necessary, if you wanna implement this from scratch, you can search on `NSCache`.

I'd suggest using **SDWebImage** or **Kingfisher** to efficiently download and cache images.

> Collection views employ a view recycling program to improve
>   efficiency. As views move offscreen, they are removed from view and
>   placed in a reuse queue instead of being deleted. As new content is
>   scrolled onscreen, views are removed from the queue and repurposed
>   with new content.

**Docs:** https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CollectionViewBasics/CollectionViewBasics.html

Comment: take a look on `.cachePolicy` from a `PFImageView`.

Comment: It doesn't have any relate properties

Comment: on a query object.

Comment: I'm not caching objects, only images with `PFImageView`

Comment: PFImageView objects have a `.cachePolicy` attribute, I really think your huge memory usage is due to not deallocating images.

Comment: `print(photoImageView.cachePolicy)` `Value of type 'PFImageView?' has no member 'cachePolicy'`